# Android, Sleeping in between vibratior methods

Tags: android, android-vibration

I am trying to get my device to vibrate every two seconds with vibrations 16 times. I used Thread.sleep() to try and sleep the thread in between method calling. In the vibrate method, it should call pattern1 and pattern2 and those already have sleep as part of it but it never does work.

```
public void vibratorDAYONE()
{
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    if(!v.hasVibrator())
    {
        Toast.makeText(daybuzzer.this,
                "You need to have a vibrator on your phone for this app to work.",      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    long[] startpattern = {1000, 500, 3000};
    long[] pattern1 = {0, 1000, 1000};//sleep one minute
    long[] pattern2 = {0, 2000, 3000}; //sleep 1.5

    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1); //1 min, 1.5 min, x8
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern1, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    v.vibrate(pattern2, -1);
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**public abstract void vibrate (long[] pattern, int repeat)**

> Added in API level 1 Vibrate with a given pattern.
>
> Pass in an array of ints that are the durations for which to turn on
>   or off the vibrator in milliseconds. The first value indicates the
>   number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on. The
>   next value indicates the number of milliseconds for which to keep the
>   vibrator on before turning it off. Subsequent values alternate between
>   durations in milliseconds to turn the vibrator off or to turn the
>   vibrator on.
>
> To cause the pattern to repeat, pass the index into the pattern array
>   at which to start the repeat, or -1 to disable repeating.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold the permission **VIBRATE**.
>
> Parameters pattern    an array of longs of times for which to turn the
>   vibrator on or off. repeat    the index into pattern at which to repeat,
>   or -1 if you don't want to repeat.

Do you have the permissions in your manifest ?